# How to generate key in Vigenère cipher which avoid punctuation marks

Tags: python, python-3.x, vigenere

I have to write Vigenère cipher but I have a problem. How to modify code to get key which ignore space, enter, comma, etc?

```
def generateKey(string, key):
    key = list(key)
    x = []
    if len(string) == len(key):
        return (key)
    else:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            x.append(key[i % len(key)])
    return ("".join(x))


    m = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    k = 'test'
    key = generateKey(m,k)
    print(key)
```

Input:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Output:

```
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
```

I want this:

```
testt estte sttes tes ttes, ttesttestte sttesttest test, tes tt esttest testte sttesttest testte st testte sttes ttestt.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalpha#str.isalpha) is what you need.

```py
def generate_key(string, key):
    key_len = len(key)
    if len(string) == key_len:
        return key
    x = []
    i = 0
    for char in string:
        if char.isalpha():
            x.append(key[i % key_len])
            i += 1
        else:
            x.append(char)
    return "".join(x)

m = ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor" 
     "incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
k = 'test'
key = generate_key(m,k)
print(key)
# 'testt estte sttes tte stte, sttesttestt esttesttes ttes, tte st testtes ttestt esttesttes tt esttes tt esttes ttest testte.'
```

To be more pythonic and avoid index manipulations, you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

def generate_key(string, key):
    if len(string) == len(key):
        return key
    key_iter = cycle(key)
    return ''.join(next(key_iter) if char.isalpha() else char for char in string)
```

Note there's an error in your expected output (missing "t" in 4th word).